# How to identify specific errors in corrupted Visual Studio 2010 .sln file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, corrupt

I've been editing my VS solution file for a complex solution with many projects in levels of solution folders. I've been changing the directory structure of the projects and updating the solution file manually. I've made a mistake somewhere as now when I try to load it in Visual Studio I get an error message:

> The selected file is a solution file, but appears to be corrupted and cannot be opened

followed by another one:

> The system cannot find the file specified

Is there any way to find out which file in particular is causing the problem? I'm sure I could fix the error manually - its a text based file format after all - if only I knew where to start looking.